# How to evaluate a DataColumn expression faster?

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, ado.net, expression-evaluation

I created a class that's responsible to evaluate an expression values for the row when I need it but the problem that when my methods works very slow in big datatables.

```
public static class RowExpressionEvaluator
{

    public static object EvaluateValue(DataRow row, string expression, Type outputType)
    {
        if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(row));
        return EvaluateValue(row.Table, row, expression, outputType);
    }


    private static object EvaluateValue(DataTable table, DataRow row, string expression, Type outputType)
    {
        if (table == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));
        if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(row));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression)) throw new ArgumentException("Expression cannot be null or empty.", nameof(expression));

        if (row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Detached)) throw new ArgumentException(@"The rowState is detached.");



        object result = null;

        using (var tempColumn = new DataColumn("Exp", outputType))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(tempColumn);

            tempColumn.Expression = expression;

            if (!row[tempColumn.ColumnName].IsDbNull())
                result = row[tempColumn.ColumnName];

            table.Columns.Remove(tempColumn);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This code works fine but its slow when the datatable contains big data

I tried to improve this code so when I have many expressions to evaluate 
then when I finish I dispose it it works better but still needs to improve because I think when I add the column with an expression the datatable evaluate it for all the rows but I need to evaluate the value only for the passed row.

like this one :

```
public sealed class BetterRowExpressionEvaluator :IDisposable
{
    private readonly DataRow _row;

    private readonly DataColumn _expressionColumn;


    public BetterRowExpressionEvaluator(DataRow row)
    {
        _row = row ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(row));
        if (row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Detached)) throw new ArgumentException(@"The rowState is detached.");

        _expressionColumn = new DataColumn("Expression",typeof(object));


        DataTable table = _row.Table;

        table.Columns.Add(_expressionColumn);


    }


    public object Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", nameof(expression));

        _expressionColumn.Expression = expression;

        return !_row[_expressionColumn.ColumnName].IsDbNull() ? _row[_expressionColumn.ColumnName] : null;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_expressionColumn == null) return;

        DataTable table = _row.Table;

        table.Columns.Remove(_expressionColumn);

        _expressionColumn?.Dispose();

    }
}
```

I did something like this to clone the row and it's parent and child relations so when I evaluate the expressions it comes faster and this is what I did :

```
    private DataSet CloneTableWithRelations(DataRow row)
    {
        var dataset = new DataSet("EvaluationDataSet") {Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture};

        dataset.Tables.Add(row.Table.Clone());
        dataset.Tables[row.Table.TableName].ImportRow(row);

        foreach (DataRelation parentRelation in row.Table.ParentRelations)
        {
            string relationName = parentRelation.RelationName;

            DataTable parentTable = parentRelation.ParentTable;

            // clone the parent table
            dataset.Tables.Add(parentTable.Clone());

            // copy the parent rows related only to the passed row
            DataRow parentRow= row.GetParentRow(relationName);
            dataset.Tables[parentTable.TableName].ImportRow(parentRow);

            DataColumn parentColumn=parentRelation.ParentColumns[0];

            DataColumn childColumn=parentRelation.ChildColumns[0];

            dataset.Relations.Add(relationName, parentColumn, childColumn,false);

        }

        foreach (DataRelation dataRelation in row.Table.ChildRelations)
        {
            DataTable childTable = dataRelation.ChildTable;

            // clone the parent table
            dataset.Tables.Add(childTable.Clone());

            // copy the parent rows related only to the passed row
            foreach (DataRow childRow in row.GetChildRows(dataRelation.RelationName))
            {
                dataset.Tables[childTable.TableName].ImportRow(childRow);
            }

            DataColumn parentColumn=dataRelation.ParentColumns[0];

            DataColumn childColumn=dataRelation.ChildColumns[0];

            dataset.Relations.Add(dataRelation.RelationName, parentColumn, childColumn,false);
        }

        return dataset;
    }
```

is there a better way to do it and more reliable way ?

Finally It works much better

when I clone the row and its parent and child data

using this class I've created

```
  public class RowCloneHandler
  {

    private readonly DataRow _row;

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters", Justification = "<Pending>")]
    public RowCloneHandler(DataRow row)
    {
        _row = row ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(row));

        if (row.RowState.Equals(DataRowState.Detached)) throw new ArgumentException("The rowState is detached.");


    }

    public DataSet CloneToDataSet()
    {
        var ClonedDataset = new DataSet { Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture };

        DataTable clonedMainTable = _row.Table.Clone();

        ClonedDataset.Tables.Add(clonedMainTable);
        ClonedDataset.Tables[_row.Table.TableName].ImportRow(_row);


        CloneParentTablesToDataset(ClonedDataset, clonedMainTable);
        CloneChildTablesToDataSet(ClonedDataset, clonedMainTable);

        return ClonedDataset;
    }

    private  void CloneChildTablesToDataSet(DataSet clonedDataset,  DataTable clonedMainTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRelation dataRelation in _row.Table.ChildRelations)
        {
            DataTable childTable = dataRelation.ChildTable;

            // clone the parent table
            DataTable clonedChildTable = childTable.Clone();

            // copy the parent rows related only to the passed row

            foreach (DataRow childRow in _row.GetChildRows(dataRelation.RelationName))
            {
                clonedChildTable.ImportRow(childRow);
            }

            clonedDataset.Tables.Add(clonedChildTable);

            DataColumn parentColumn = clonedMainTable.Columns[dataRelation.ParentColumns[0].ColumnName];

            DataColumn childColumn = clonedChildTable.Columns[dataRelation.ChildColumns[0].ColumnName];

            clonedDataset.Relations.Add(dataRelation.RelationName, parentColumn, childColumn, false);
        }
    }

    private  void CloneParentTablesToDataset(DataSet clonedDataset,  DataTable clonedMainTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRelation parentRelation in _row.Table.ParentRelations)
        {

            DataTable parentTable = parentRelation.ParentTable;

            // clone the parent table
            DataTable clonedParentTable = parentTable.Clone();

            // copy the parent rows related only to the passed row
            DataRow parentRow = _row.GetParentRow(parentRelation.RelationName);

            clonedParentTable.ImportRow(parentRow);

            clonedDataset.Tables.Add(clonedParentTable);

            DataColumn parentColumn = clonedParentTable.Columns[parentRelation.ParentColumns[0].ColumnName];

            DataColumn childColumn = clonedMainTable.Columns[parentRelation.ChildColumns[0].ColumnName];

            clonedDataset.Relations.Add(parentRelation.RelationName, parentColumn, childColumn, false);

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone) of your `DataTable`, [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.importrow) the `DataRow` to the cloned `DataTable`, and then add the computed column in the cloned `DataTable`. Here are some extension methods that do exactly that.

**Update:** I revised the code to take into account the existing relations with other tables. The code became much more complicated because now the cloned table must be placed inside the existing `DataSet`, and the existing relations must be also cloned, and temporary renamed. The cloned relations are created without constraints, so hopefully the performance will not be negatively affected.

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static object Compute(this DataRow dataRow, string expression)
    {
        using (var clonedDT = CloneDataTable(dataRow))
        {
            clonedDT.ImportRow(dataRow);
            var clonedRow = clonedDT.Rows[0];
            var dataColumn = clonedDT.Columns.Add(null, typeof(object), expression);
            return clonedRow[dataColumn];
        }
    }

    public static T Compute<T>(this DataRow dataRow, string expression)
    {
        using (var clonedDT = CloneDataTable(dataRow))
        {
            clonedDT.ImportRow(dataRow);
            var clonedRow = clonedDT.Rows[0];
            var dataColumn = clonedDT.Columns.Add(null, typeof(T), expression);
            return clonedRow.Field<T>(dataColumn);
        }
    }

    public static T? ComputeNullable<T>(this DataRow dataRow, string expression)
        where T : struct
    {
        using (var clonedDT = CloneDataTable(dataRow))
        {
            clonedDT.ImportRow(dataRow);
            var clonedRow = clonedDT.Rows[0];
            var dataColumn = clonedDT.Columns.Add(null, typeof(T), expression);
            return clonedRow.Field<T?>(dataColumn);
        }
    }

    private static DataTable CloneDataTable(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        var dataTable = dataRow.Table;
        var dataSet = dataRow.Table.DataSet;
        if (dataSet == null) return dataTable.Clone();
        var clonedDT = dataSet.Tables.Add();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            clonedDT.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
        }
        var relationsAdded = new List<
            (DataRelation Cloned, DataRelation Original)>();
        foreach (var relation in dataTable.ParentRelations
            .Cast<DataRelation>().ToArray())
        {
            var relationName = relation.RelationName;
            relation.RelationName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var clonedColumns = relation.ChildColumns
                .Select(c => clonedDT.Columns[c.ColumnName]).ToArray();
            var clonedRelation = dataSet.Relations.Add(relationName,
                relation.ParentColumns, clonedColumns, createConstraints: false);
            relationsAdded.Add((clonedRelation, relation));
        }
        foreach (var relation in dataTable.ChildRelations
            .Cast<DataRelation>().ToArray())
        {
            var relationName = relation.RelationName;
            relation.RelationName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var clonedColumns = relation.ParentColumns
                .Select(c => clonedDT.Columns[c.ColumnName]).ToArray();
            var clonedRelation = dataSet.Relations.Add(relationName,
                clonedColumns, relation.ChildColumns, createConstraints: false);
            relationsAdded.Add((clonedRelation, relation));
        }
        clonedDT.Disposed += (s, e) => // Cleanup
        {
            clonedDT.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var entry in relationsAdded)
            {
                dataSet.Relations.Remove(entry.Cloned);
                entry.Original.RelationName = entry.Cloned.RelationName;
            }
            clonedDT.Columns.Clear();
            dataSet.Tables.Remove(clonedDT);
        };
        return clonedDT;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
dt.Rows.Add(10);
decimal doublePrice = dt.Rows[0].Compute<decimal>("Price * 2");
Console.WriteLine(doublePrice);
```

Output:

> 20

Comment: the problem that I have some expressions that depends on the relations on the dataset will that work also fine ? I'll test your code

Comment: It didn't work maybe if I could get the child and parent tables related to this row.

Comment: Because I have some expressions like this :sum(Child([relationName]).[Net])

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work. It is more complex than I thought.

Comment: I edited my question and I added how I'm trying to clone the row and its relations

Comment: Now using your extensions it works much better. Thank you. if you have any suggestions please tell me. thanks again

Comment: @Shehab I updated my answer. Hopefully it's not buggy now.